# Is there an "anonymous" generic tag in C#, like '?' in Java?

Tags: c#, generics, syntax

In Java, one can declare a variable parameterised by an "unknown" generic type, which looks like this:

```
Foo<?> x;
```

Is there an equivalent construct to this question-mark, in C#?

Comment: What is the template type finally resolved?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The short answer is no. There isn't an equivalent feature in C#.

A workaround, from [C# from a Java developer's perspective](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html#generics) by Dare Obasanjo:

In certain cases, one may need create a method that can operate on data structures containing any type as opposed to those that contain a specific type (e.g. a method to print all the objects in a data structure) while still taking advantage of the benefits of strong typing in generics. The mechanism for specifying this in C# is via a feature called generic type inferencing while in Java this is done using wildcard types. The following code samples show how both approaches lead to the same result.

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 

class Test{

    //Prints the contents of any generic Stack by 
    //using generic type inference 
    public static void PrintStackContents<T>(Stack<T> s){
        while(s.Count != 0){
            Console.WriteLine(s.Pop()); 
        } 
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args){

    Stack<int> s2 = new Stack<int>(); 
    s2.Push(4); 
    s2.Push(5); 
    s2.Push(6); 

    PrintStackContents(s2);     

    Stack<string> s1 = new Stack<string>(); 
    s1.Push("One"); 
    s1.Push("Two"); 
    s1.Push("Three"); 

    PrintStackContents(s1); 
    }
}
```

Java Code

```
import java.util.*; 

class Test{

    //Prints the contents of any generic Stack by 
    //specifying wildcard type 
    public static void PrintStackContents(Stack<?> s){
        while(!s.empty()){
            System.out.println(s.pop()); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Stack <Integer> s2 = new Stack <Integer>(); 
    s2.push(4); 
    s2.push(5); 
    s2.push(6); 

    PrintStackContents(s2);     

    Stack<String> s1 = new Stack<String>(); 
    s1.push("One"); 
    s1.push("Two"); 
    s1.push("Three");   

    PrintStackContents(s1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The C#-like inference works also in Java 6. Is there still use of <?> in Java then?

Comment: This is not actually answering the question. The answer is "no". The trick shown above demonstrates a workaround for Java's capture conversion in C# that works with method invocation conversion, but won't be useful in assignment conversion or in a cast expression.

Comment: In fact, this answer is the longest way of saying "no" I've ever seen :)

Comment: Ok, ok. I added de 'no' at the beginning. :) And guys, you know you can edit my answer, right?.

Comment: In my opinion, phenomenal answer, because obviously a Java developer transitioning to C# would need to see that similar goals are achievable in C# while they must be accomplished using different patterns.  In my opinion, great answer, because the example code is simple enough to be previewed quickly, yet the differences are clear enough to communicate the concepts without a long explanation.  In my opinion, good answer because while method invocation and assignment conversion are fairly simple, the capture example would be the most difficult to figure out for someone new to C#.

Comment: Shouldn't call it "workaround" as it isn't. It's mere example how it is done, no?

Comment: @Mishax it wasn't the answer I was looking for, but it was the answer I needed

Answer (score 31):

AFAIK you can not do that in C#. What the BCL does and there are plenties of examples there is to create a class that is not generic and then create a generic class that inherits the base behavior from the previous one. See example below.

```
class Foo
{
}

class Foo<T> : Foo
{
}
```

The you can write something like this:

```
Foo t = new Foo<int>();
```

Answer (score 15):

While admittedly being not the clean approach, using `Foo<object> x` may also be suitable.

Comment: -1: using `object` restrict the generic type to all types that have the common super class `object`.

Comment: Works with everything: primitives, class objects, structs, enums... `List<object> list = new List<object>(); list.Add(1); list.Add(new DateTime()); list.Add(new MyStruct()); list.Add(MyEnum.Enum1);`

Comment: @Dani, `List<object>.Add` boxes any struct types into `Nullable<>`s, thus marc's comment still holds.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work when there are type constraints.

Comment: This answer resolved my problem immediately.  I'm calling a generic method and I'm completely ignoring the return value, so I care even less about the return type.  Using `object` works perfectly for me.  +1

Comment: I have one interface, but need to use it with multiple return types, none of which are descendants of each other, and in some cases I ignore the return type completely. This worked absolutely perfectly.

Comment: good luck casting from that to any other type.

Answer (score 8):

It isn't (quite) true that there is no equivalent in C#. There is no static equivalent that you can use as a type, or call methods on, true enough. For that, use [Jorge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116830/is-there-an-anonymous-generic-tag-in-c-like-in-java#116881).

On the other hand, sometimes you need the equivalent idea for reflection, and there is an equivalent there. If you have:

```
interface IFoo<T>
{
  T Bar(T t, int n);
}
```

you can get a `Type` that represents `IFoo<int>` using `typeof(IFoo<int>)`. Less well known, and a partial answer to your question, is that you can also get a `Type` that represents `IFoo<T>` using `typeof(IFoo<>)`.

This is useful when you want to use `IFoo<T>` for some `T` through reflection and won't know `T` until runtime.

```
Type theInterface = typeof(IFoo<>);
Type theSpecificInterface = theInterface.MakeGenericType(typeof(string));

// theSpecificInterface now holds IFoo<string> even though we may not have known we wanted to use string until runtime

// proceed with reflection as normal, make late bound calls / constructions, emit DynamicMethod code, etc.
```

Answer (score 5):

There isn't an equivalent syntax in C#.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't really the same concept in C#.  You would need to refer to a base class of Foo (maybe a non-generic Foo), or make the method you're working in generic itself (so that you can refer to Foo, and let the caller of your method determine what T is).

Hope that helps.