# How do I specify a C# return value with an ambiguous generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

In C#, suppose I have two interfaces: `Foo<in P, out C>` and `Bar<C>`. Also suppose I have two implementations of `Bar<int>`: `BarOne` and `BarTwo`.

I want to add a method `Baz()` on `Bar<C>` that returns something like:

```
public interface Bar<C> {
  // other methods, some of which use C as a type
  // then:
  Foo<..., C> Baz ();
}

public class BarOne : Bar<int> {
  // other methods...
  private class FooImplOne : Foo<string, int> {
    // stuff here
  }
  Foo<string, int> Baz() {
    return new FooImplOne();
  }
}

public class BarTwo : Bar<int> {
  // other methods...
  private class FooImplTwo : Foo<long, int> {
    // stuff here
  }
  Foo<long, int> Baz() {
    return new FooImplTwo();
  }
}
```

But I can't say anything about the first parameter of `Foo` in `Baz`'s return in the definition of the `Bar` interface. In java I'd use `Foo<?, C>` as the return type in the `Bar` definition - what do I do in C#?

I found a [2008 stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116830/is-there-an-anonymous-generic-tag-in-c-like-in-java#116881) that tells me "In C# you can't do that, and need to define a base interface for `Foo<P, C>` that only has the generic parameter `C` and return that base type instead".

Is that still the case in modern, 2016 C#?

Comment: It is not exactly clear what do you want. As it seems Michael's answer fits the bill.

Comment: I added more code details to clarify why Michael's answer is inadequate.

Comment: So in Java, i have a class which has `IBar<int> x = bar;`. What type do I actually get back when I call `x.Baz()`? Say `it was  `? Baz()` which sometimes returns long sometimes string. How can I call `x.Baz() * x.Baz()` if my class does not know the actual implementation?

Comment: In Java, you'd do `Foo<?, int> xbaz = x.Baz();` (well, `Foo<?, Integer>` because Java's unboxing is clumsy). You can call methods on `xbaz` that don't depend on the first type param, and if there's a method that only returns the first type param (and doesn't accept it as an argument), you can call that and statically get an `Object` back.

Comment: @MichalCiechan - I think I answered your question, but the positioning of backticks in your comment makes me think that I might have missed something in what you were asking.

Comment: Shouldn't you then state that as Foo<object, C> Baz() in your interface, because that is really what this method returns? And then _explicitly_ implement that interface in BarOne and BarTwo. So those who use BarOne directly will see Foo<string, int>, and those who use through interface - Foo<object, int>.

Comment: @Evk If the first type parameter on `Foo` were an `out` parameter, sure. Unfortunately, it's an `in` parameter.

Comment: And why exactly your Foo has this parameter as "in"? I mean, the way you want to use it suggests it shouldn't be "in".

Comment: It has the first parameter at all - and that parameter is an `in` parameter - because of methods I haven't shown in the example. (specifically, there's a method that takes a `P` and turns it into a `C`, but there are also other methods that don't involve `P`)

Comment: Shouldn't that method have method level type parameter (C TurnIntoC<P>(P value)) insead of class level? All in all I doubt there is a direct workaround for what you want to do, because if for example you have List<string>, and you use it as List<?>, you will be able to add non-strings to that list which is not possible. Not sure how Java handles that.

Comment: @Evk How Java handles that is that if you have a List<?>, you can't call any methods that take something of the parameter type (so you can't call `.add(T)`), but you can call methods that *return* something of the parameter type (so you can call `.get(int)`).

Answer (score 4):

In C# you would also make the Method a generic method with a different type parameter local to that method

e.g.

```
public interface Bar<C> {
  Foo<T, C> Baz<T>();
}
```

[See MSDN: Generic Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

Comment: That would work if each of my `Bar<C>` implementations could return `Foo<T, C>` for all `T`. But I'm looking at two concrete implementations `BarOne : Bar<int>` and `BarTwo : Bar<int>`, and `BarOne.Baz()` can only return a `Foo<string, int>` and `BarTwo.Baz()` can only return a `Foo<long, int>`.

Comment: @DanielMartin Then you will have to go with pm100's answer, or make it return `object`

Comment: @DanielMartin so yes just use return object. Be aware that it will box all your return values if they are reference values.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
public interface Bar<T1,T2> {
  Foo<T1, T2> Baz ();
}
```

ie pass both Foo type params in

Comment: Because the `T1` type is really an implementation detail of `Bar`; there's absolutely no reason for most `Bar` clients to know about which type that is.

Comment: @DanielMartin The compiler needs to know which implementation for a given interface. If you have an object of type `IBar<int>` how is the compiler supposed to know what actual return type `Foo<T2,int>` is. The whole point of making it static. Therefore you need `BarOne : IBar<string, int>`, and `BarTwo : IBar<long, int>`

Comment: It's not though like I'm asking for something that can't be done at all for some fundamental reason - this is _trivial_ to do in Java, and I can hack around it myself by introducing another named interface for `FooWithoutTheFirstTypeParameter<P>`, making `Foo` descend from that, and returning that instead. I had just hoped that I could avoid adding another thing to the list of "stuff java can do easily that C# makes you work for".

Comment: @DanielMartin If that parameter is an implementation detail why is it being exposed in the interface?

Comment: @Kyle From the perspective of things using `Bar`, it's an implementation detail. Things asking for `Foo` are already asking for slightly lower-level stuff, and in fact the implementations of `Bar` actually only use their `Foo` values through the interface. So this points more in the direction that `Bar.Baz()` should be returning a non-generic superinterface of `Foo` that doesn't have on it the methods that involve `C` or `P`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `<?>` is shorthand for `<? extends Object>`.  This means that the code that is trying to use it only knows that it is an object.  The equivalent in C# would just be using `<object>`, so your interface would just be

```
Foo<object, C> Baz ();
```

Comment: After all that :| `?` = `object`. This is why I hate Java :-P

Comment: No, it isn't equivalent. Or rather, it isn't equivalent in all cases, and this is one of those cases. If the first parameter on `Foo` were an `out` parameter, this would work. Unfortunately...

Comment: Specifically, in java it's _very_ different if you have a `List<?>` versus a `List<Object>`: with both of those you can pull stuff from the list (and get an Object) but with the first you can also add to the list, because you know that `.add()` can take an `Object`. With a `List<?>`, you don't know what type `add` accepts, so can't call it.

Comment: @DanielMartin In/out can only be declared on interfaces/delegates in C#.  Returning an IFoo, with `interface IFoo<in T1, T2>` might get you where you need to go, but if the first parameter is an implementation detail, and an in param, why is it in the interface at all?