# Generic class containing a generic list of different type

Tags: c#

I am getting into generics and I have an issue of deciding which approach is better for having a generic class contain a generic list which is not of the same type as the containing class e.g.

```
public class Goal<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public List<Goal<T>> Dependencies { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public Goal(string name, int priority, T val)
    {
        Name = name;
        Priority = priority;
        Value = val;
        Dependencies = new List<Goal<T>>();
    }
}
```

What is the best way to have the 'Dependencies' in the list be able to be of a different type then the containing class?

Thanks

Comment: you mean in `Dependencies` to have a different `T`?

Comment: yes exactly. just edited my answer to better illustrate it.

Comment: This is not easily achievable in C#. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116830/is-there-an-anonymous-generic-tag-in-c-like-in-java for further info.

Comment: For all those answers which suggests to do `class Goal<T, W>` . I feel it is cheating on question statment. "class contain a generic list which is not of the same type as the containing class" is question while now generic class will have knowledge of two types!

Comment: @Amit (1) It's not cheating, it's pointing out the technical requirements. Just because you can think of it doesn't mean it makes always logical sense. Using a generic type without having to declare it simply makes no sense from the compiler's perspective. (2) `class Goal<T, W>` isn't even possible in this case.

Comment: @Flater I have it in my working project with 4 to 5 levels of hierarchies. So i know that.

Comment: @Amit: I assume that your comment is in reference to (2). Multiple generic types are allowed in C# in general, but you can't recurse them the way OP is expecting to. Note that OP's parent and child classes are both the same `Goal<>` class. If his child class had been anything else (e.g. `Keeper<>`), then it wouldn't have been a problem (unless you then create an endless loop between the classes, which again creates the same issue)

Comment: @Flater i understand, question is little more tricky here, and I also admit i dont have perfect solution for that (counting the one which we are discussing is not perfect). still I commented what i could thought logically.

Comment: You can have the generic `Goal<T>` inherit from a non-generic abstract `Goal` and make that the type contained in the list. But then you'll need runtime type checks and/or casts, losing many of the benefits of having generics in the first place.

Comment: @Ruptr do you have knowledge of all possible types which `Goal` can have ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It would seem that changing the approach might be a better solution. Maybe it would make more sense to have identifiers (of e.g. char type) for each type of 'target' or 'value' instead?

Comment: Yes, I know all the types.

Comment: @Ruptr "Factory design pattern" might help you, Hold the base interface in Goal and all other classes should implement them. as Damien suggested, there will be casting. but proper implementation will prevent all coupling in code. it will be smooth

Comment: @Ruptr don't just give up on this approach. at least have a shot.

Comment: interesting approach, but would a factory not create new objects as opposed to storing objects passed as parameters?

Comment: @Amit: The desired setup is logically impossible. Recursing `Goal<>` classes in each other with different generic types on every level renders the developer **unable** to ever declare a finite type.

Comment: Is the other type you want a subclass of `T` or an implementation of interface `T`, or are `T` and the other type unrelated?

Comment: @Flater yes. I agree on that.

Answer (score 1):

The only generic solution is to explicitly declare the second generic type.

```
public class Goal<T, TChild>
{
    public T value { get; set; }
    public List<TChild> MyListWithAnotherType { get; set; }
}
```

However, since you are using this class recursively (referencing a `Goal<U>` inside a `Goal<T>`), this becomes impossible. If you tried to do this, you'd see that it would require you to provide an infinite chain of generic type arguments, ince you always have to specify the type of the child goals, which is a neverending sequence (every child has its own children, and so on...)

This can't be solved the way you want to solve it. But with a more elaborate problem description, there may be a different approach to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I am making a multiagent-system with BDI agents, which can have goals of different types. I am trying to have the goal class contain the actual objects being pursued by the agent, e.g. one goal may be 'find', which I then would like to contain the target (another Agent, a Location or whatever). Furthermore the goal containing the value Agent as the target, may depend on other goals where the target/value is a room (class) or something else. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ruptr: There are options here, but the one you want isn't available. Google "C# recursive classes" and you'll find a treasure trove of examples. You can do it without a generic type, or you can do it with a _repeating_ generic type (always using `T` on every level - like in your question). You can't create it in a way that you can always switch between types on every level, as that would then require you to infinitely list the types you want to use when you want to declare a `Goal<>` variable. If you want to switch types per level, you need to hardcode (= non-generically define) them.

Comment: just to be clear - by hardcoding you mean e.g. a subclass of the goal class for each individual goal?

Comment: @Ruptr: I meant specifying the exact type you want instead of using a type parameter. E.g. `class AgentGoal : Goal<Agent> { public List<FindGoal> Dependencies  {get;set;}  }` (where `class FindGoal : Goal<FindAction>`). This means that you can declare the generic type of each level separately, without having to collapse them all into one infinite type definition. You retain the original `Goal<T>` class, but instead of expanding it to a `Goal<T,U,V,...>` class, you instead **implement** the `Goal<T>` in other (non-generic) classes.