# Is it possible to reference a generic class object without specifying its type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this generic class :

```
public class Grid<TGridObject> {

    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public float CellSize { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create another class called **GridDebugger**, its role is to draw lines and texts based on the settings and content of the Grid class.
So ultimately i would have something like this:

```
public class GridDebugger {
    
        private Grid<TGridObject> grid
        public void DebugGrid(){
         //debug the grid
        }
    }
```

The problem is that of course i cannot declare with TGridObject cause it doesn't exists in the current content, i can change that line to :

```
private Grid<bool> grid
```

And now that i have a grid of bool i can debug it, but i want to have a generic gridDebugging class that can work with any grid type.

Is this possible ?

Thank you

Comment: You can also make the `GridDebugger` also a generic and use its generic type for your `Grid` definition, but I'm not quite clear if that is exactly what you are after.

Comment: @BradfordDillon i could do that but now i have to create a specific instance of the GridDebugger too, the goal was to drag and drop the GridDebugger class and have it debug any Grid (this is Unity btw)

Comment: Check this answer [Is there an “anonymous” generic tag in C#, like '?' in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116830/is-there-an-anonymous-generic-tag-in-c-like-in-java)

Comment: Perhaps a generic `DebugGrid` method would be more useful if that is what you are going for in that case?

Comment: hmm.. "drag and drop the class" is an really abstract, unspecific requirement and concept (beyond unity3d... perhaps).  should tag this question appropriately and add this scenario to the question.  (you would need to understand what is going on with this drag and drop operation in this context to provide a better answer beyond what's provided already)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the code below?

```
public class GridDebugger<TGridObject> {
    
        private Grid<TGridObject> grid
        public void DebugGrid(){
         //debug the grid
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to debug any grid type with the `GridDebugger` it sounds like you might be better off with a generic `DebugGrid` method than a generic grid member.

```
public class GridDebugger
{
    //stuff
    public void DebugGrid<TGridObject>(Grid<TGridObject> grid) { //stuff }
}
```

At that point you can debug a grid of any type with the same `GridDebugger` as long as no logic is specific to the type of the `TGridObject`.